# Raspberry Pi Camera streaming Video to Nvidia Xavier NX using python OpenCv loses Color Information

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, gstreamer

Raspberry Pi 0w Camera runs:

```
raspivid -n -t 0 -rot 180 -w 640 -h 480 -fps 30 -b 1000000 -o - | gst-launch-1.0 -e -vvvv fdsrc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay pt=96 config-interval=5 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.242 port=5000
```

Xavier NX to test from OS runs fine with color:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, media=video, clock-rate=90000, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 !  rtph264depay ! decodebin ! autovideoconvert ! ximagesink
```

Xavier NX python OpenCV code - Missing Color(Gray video) - When I print the frame .shape I get Height and Width, No Color info:

```
import cv2

cam0 = cv2.VideoCapture('udpsrc port=5000 caps = "application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264, payload=96"'
    ' !  rtph264depay' 
    ' ! decodebin'
    ' ! autovideoconvert'
    ' ! appsink', cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

while True:
    _, frameCam0 = cam0.read()
    print(frameCam0.shape)
    cv2.imshow("Camera 0", frameCam0)
    cv2.moveWindow("Camera 0", 0, 0)

    if cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q'):   
        break
cam0.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It seems that there's a negotiation problem inside Gstreamer. What happens if you specyfy caps before appsink?

 ' ! autovideoconvert'
' ! video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR'
    ' ! appsink'

Comment: I've tried moving around as you suggested: Program just hang at:
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 261 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 261